# Ratio of quadratic forms of powers of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix that is positive definite. Let $y \in R^n$, $y \neq 0 $, then

$lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\frac{y' A^{m+1} y}{y' A^m y}$ , select correct

1. Does not exist
2. Exist and equal to eigenvector of A
3. Exist and equal to eigenvalue of A
4. Exist and equal to any real number

Please help me with solution of this.

Comment: Have you attempted a simulation with a software like Matlab and random S.P.D. matrices in order at least to have a "prognose" whether 1,2,3,4 is the good answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a symmetric matrix is always diagonalizable (http://control.ucsd.edu/mauricio/courses/mae280a/lecture11.pdf)

Moreover, $A$ can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $P$, meaning that we can write :

$$\tag{1} A=PDP^{-1}=PDP^{T}$$

with $D=diag(\lambda_1, \ \lambda_2, \ ... \lambda_n).$

Moreover, $A$ being positive definite, we can assume:

$$\tag{*}\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq  ... \geq \lambda_n>0.$$

From (1), we can deduce : $$y^T A^{m} y=y^T PD^{m}P^{T} y= (P^Ty)^T D^{m} (P^{T} y)= $$

$$=z^T D^{m} z=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k^m z_k^2,$$

where $z$ is defined as $z:=P^Ty$, and $z_k \ (k=1...n)$ are the coordianates of $z.$

Thus:

$$\frac{y^T A^{m+1} y}{y^T A^m y}= \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k^{m+1} z_k^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k^m z_k^2}$$

Now, for the sake of simplicity of presentation, let us take $n=2$.

Let us factorize $\lambda_1^{m+1}$ in the numerator and  $\lambda_1^{m}$ in the denominator.

$$\frac{\lambda_1^{m+1} z_1^2+\lambda_2^{m+1} z_2^2}{\lambda_1^{m} z_1^2+\lambda_2^{m} z_2^2}=\frac{\lambda_1^{m+1}z_1^2}{\lambda_1^{m}z_1^2} \times \frac{1+k^2 \rho^{m+1}}{1+k^2 \rho^{m}}$$

where

$$\rho:=\tfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \ \ \ k:=\tfrac{z_2}{z_1}.$$

$\lambda_1$ being the largest eigenvalue of matrix $A$, we have $\rho \leq 1$. Thus:

$$\text{If} \ m \to \infty, \ \ \ \frac{\lambda_1^{m+1}z_1^2}{\lambda_1^{m}z_1^2} \times \frac{1+k^2 \rho^{m+1}}{1+k^2 \rho^{m}} \ \to \ \lambda_1$$

Therefore, the right answer is Answer #3.

Comment: Well, that is where I got stuck. I am thinking it could be any real number lying between the maximum and minimum eigen values

Comment: I will add an edit to my answer to explain it.

Comment: Yeah sure. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited a bit more. Thanks